# Deleting massive number of duplicate records without using a new table

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-delete

Right now I have a table that has a massive number of duplicates that need to be deleted (about 500 million).

I have a query that will delete all the duplicates, but it is unable to finish the whole query due to the transaction log being filled up.

Moving the nonduplicates to a new table, then renaming it, would work, but in this scenario I am not able to do it this way. This will be performed in a production environment so I can not drop that d1 table.

Same with the other solution that involved changing some sort of backup transaction log setting.

This is my query:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        d_id, d_record, d_d2id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d_record, d_d2id ORDER BY d_id) RowNumber
    FROM 
        d1
    WHERE 
        d_d2id >= 25 AND d_d2id <= 28
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

Obviously this will work, however due to the amount of deletes this will have to perform, it will blow up the transaction log.

Is there a way to create this specific CTE then go through it in batches of 1000 records and deleting them that way thus leaving a whole bunch of transactions instead of 1? Or is there another way I can accomplish this? The only solution I have is to loop through these duplicates and delete them without blowing up the transaction log.

Thanks!

Comment: Might there be some way to turn of transaction logging within SQL Server?  Your current query (at least) already seems pretty optimal.

Comment: You could add another CTE term which filters out just RowNumber > 1, then adds another row_number over ALL the remaining rows, then deleting only the first N of these for each batch / commit.  Rinse, repeat until done.  Some databases support some form of FETCH FIRST N ROWS, which could be used instead of the second row_number expression.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your "obviously this will work" is totally incorrect, given that your non-standard code only works in one database, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can delete in batches.  Although this is not the most efficient code, it illustrates the idea of deleting in batches:

```
DECLARE @go_on INT
SELECT @go_on = 1;

WHILE (@go_on = 1)
BEGIN
    WITH TODELETE AS (
          SELECT TOP (10000) d1.*
          FROM (SELECT d1.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d_record, d_d2id ORDER BY d_id) as seqnum
                FROM d1
                WHERE d_d2id >= 25 AND d_d2id <= 28
               ) d1
          WHERE seqnum > 1
         )
    DELETE FROM TODELETE; 

    SET @go_on = (CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
END;
```

It would be more efficient to store the rows to be deleted in a temporary table or table variable, so they don't need to be recalculated each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor to do your deletes in batches. These are often considered bad practice but it does what you're trying to do here.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 option

> 1st , let system memories 1 occurrence record position and delete rest of entries with same values

> > 2nd see you can scan and delete entry with 2 or more condition, but it has to store your data somewhere,
> > making a temporary table with unique/primary constraint is way faster, other wise system might crash or go slow while operating , example record RD002 found at 1st, but system has to memories that 1st entry's position and scan rest of table > same with other duplicate and unique entries (to delete other entries also same situation will occur)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the rows in batches of 1000 and commit after each deletion. You can do this in pl/sql loop:

```
begin
    loop

        delete from d1
        where d1.rowid in (
            select t.rowid
            from (
                select 
                    d1.rowid, 
                    row_number() over (partition by d_record, d_d2id order by d_id) rn
                from d1
                where 
                    d_d2id >= 25 and d_d2id <= 28
            ) t
            where t.rn > 1 and rownum <= 1000
        );

        commit;
    exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
    end loop;
end;
```